# Unable to generate model: "You have already activated multi_json 1.7.2, but your Gemfile requires multi_json 1.4.0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

Here's what I put in:

$ rails generate scaffold Foobar content:string

Here's what I get:

```
/Users/nsbarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated multi_json 1.7.2, but your Gemfile requires multi_json 1.4.0. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/nsbarr/rails_projects/poems_io/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/nsbarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. Here's my Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

gem 'twilio-ruby'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '2.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem "therubyracer"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

gem 'annotate', '2.5.0', group: :development

group :production do
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I was previously able to generate models on this app so I'm not sure what happened in the interim. Wasn't able to find anything by searching the error message. Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command and everything should be OK:

```
bundle exec rails generate scaffold Foobar content:string
```